# Yii::app()->request did not get $_POST values

Tags: post, yii

I am new to Yii framework and I am having trouble with retrieving data from my form. In my controller I wrote:

```
$request = Yii::app()->request;
$form = $request->getPost('createProjectForm');
var_dump($form);
```

Whenever I submit, the form is null. However, if I var_dump($_POST), I still get the values. Can anyone tell me what is wrong? Thank you very much and sorry for my bad English.

Comment: What does `print_r($_POST)` output?

Comment: @Jon After I input some random values into my form, this is what it shows:
Array ( [CreateProjectForm] => Array ( [project_name] => yii project [description] => this is a yii project [category_id] => 12 [estimated_size] => 12,000 USD [max_bid] => 12000 [bid_close_date] => 2012-04-13 09:12:54 [project_deadline] => 2012-04-20 09:13:00 ) [yt0] => Submit )

Comment: Well, there it is. `createProjectForm` in your code and `CreateProjectForm` (capital C) being submitted.

Comment: thank you, my problem is now solved :)

Answer (score -6, accepted):

this is the getPost function and it returns the $_POST array

```
public function getPost($name,$defaultValue=null)
{
   return isset($_POST[$name]) ? $_POST[$name] : $defaultValue;
}
```

could you tell what is the result of this code in your action

```
var_dump(isset($_POST['CreateProjectForm']));
```

Comment: This `var_dump` will obviously give `false`, otherwise the question would not have been asked.

Comment: this is not the Yii way, he was using the correct way to do it